# What's the most optimal container consisting of two spacial figures?

Tags: optimization, geometry

I asked myself this question as I was answering an optimization question where I had to figure out what three dimensional shape had the best volume-surface area ratio. Which I find to be a sqhere. It optimizes the volume better than any other shape with the same surface area and I believe it's because it basically has a center where the surface is drawn from an equal distance all around it. A cube on the other hand has a longer distance from its center to its corners than just to the center of its flat surfaces. So this got me thinking, if I had to use two different three dimensional shapes and put them together in whatever way I want, what would be the most optimal?
I thought of two spheres put together somehow but I'm not sure and I'd like to hear what you guys think? Or maybe a way to figure out what's best?

Comment: `Optimal` is enough.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment?

Comment: Which use is `most` in `most optimal`, considering that `optimal` alone calls for... well, an optimum?

Comment: It's more optimal to use gasoline as fuel for my car instead of water. It doesn't necessarily make it the most optimal.
However, this has nothing to do with the question at hand - do you have an answer?

Comment: From a dictionary: *optimal 1. The best, most favourable or desirable, especially under some restriction*. // If, as you say, *this has nothing to do with the matter at hand*, why don't you correct your title without further fuss?

Comment: The two halves of a cube joined by their common face do better than two tangent spheres of common radius.

Comment: Why do you get so worked up by such a small thing? That's a better question. Is it because you dont know the answer or because you want to show off your linguistic ingenuity on a math forum?
I dont think either is a reason to get that worked up about it, as all I'm looking for is an answer to my question and not a grammar lesson.

Comment: Worked up? Small modifications of grammar and maths are common practice on the site and are usually swiftly dealt with. You choose to react otherwise, this is your problem. Say, did you have the time to read my math comment or were you too "worked up" to do so?

Comment: I agree that "most optimal" does not really make sense. Something is optimal or it's not. The question is also too vague. How should the two figures be put together? Should it be two *half* figures? The sphere is the same as two half spheres put together.

Comment: I didn't care for your math comment because of your snarky grammar nazi look-alike comment. It's obviously only meant as an insult and not constructive what-so-ever. Any person with a reasonable about of intelligence will be able to decipher the code that is "most optimal". That's also a response to your comment Dominique and to respond to your other question, it's really as simple as I stated. Two shapes put together in whatever way you see fit. I never said two half spheres - I said two spheres put together in some way. There are many ways they can be put together without becoming a sphere.

Comment: Baha'u'llah related a story of a 'learned grammarian' who set out with a 'mystic knower'  they came to the sea and the knower straightway flung himself into the waves while the grammarian stood lost in his reasoning.  The knower said "Forget what thou didst learn in the (grammar) books and come into the sea".  One must be forgetful of self if one is to cross the ocean. I find that many school-taught people will consider certain ways of saying things as hard to handle, while self-taught will see the main concept behind the question.